# Best algorithm to fetch top five records from a real time dynamic data set with infinite length

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, real-time

suppose we have a set of  dynamic records having some values
 ( 7,8,1,15,3,31,63,21,9,..... ( and so on , values keep on updating in real time ))

what is the best approach/ algorithm to fetch top 5 values from this real time increasing dynamic data set ?

Note : for above example , till this point , result should be (63,31,21,15,9)

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @Oliver , I was trying to know the real time sorting algorithm.

Comment: @Mark can you name any algorithm for this ?

Comment: How is the data stored?  Hash or List?

Comment: @jdweng it can be an array or a list .

Comment: You can never get to the end of an infinite length list so you will never be able to complete the task if you already have data in the list.  So the assumption is you are trying to collect the five best records in real time from the start of the dynamic data.  So the best algorithm is to take the 1st 5 items and sort them.  Then put new item sorted into the existing list and throw out the smallest item array.  This would require an average of 3 comparisons.  So the algorithm would by 3N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using"real-time sort". You should use a heap (priority queue) data structure of the top 5. If the next value is above the min, then you would do a delete min, then insert the new value. The priority queue allows you to quickly find the minimum value, delete it, and add a new value.

You can maintain the value by adding 5th of the difference between the new value and the new value(only when the new value is better than the 5th value).

Comment: Thanks .. this helped